# Is There A Way To Change The Class Used By Simple Form When Marking An Input Group As 'required'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, required

When a field is required, Simple form adds a class of `required` to the container wrapping the input and label.

I would like the class added to be `is-required` instead of `required`, but I can find no configuration option to specify the class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb, or wherever you deem appropriate
module SimpleForm
  module Helpers
    module Required
      def required_class
        required_field? ? 'is-required' : 'optional'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I recommend testing thoroughly (as I haven't)!